API Error: message: Missing Authentication Token
I am encountering an issue where the ApiKey header is being forwarded but for some reason not with the apikey itself.
I am using kotlin language in Android Studio
Would really appreciate the help, as this is my first time posting here and am relatively new to api integration
If anything is missing or need more info, please ask for it
tried explicitly adding the API key to the request header using an OkHttp interceptor
and hardcoding it to the header but still wouldn't resolve it
so i am kind of lost on what to do
Here is my retrofit class that i use
object RetrofitClient {
    val instance: SightHoundApiService by lazy {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("X-API-KEY", BuildConfig.API_KEY) // Set the X-API-KEY header explicitly
                    .build()
                chain.proceed(newRequest)
            }
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS))
            .build()

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL) // Base URL for the API
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // Convert JSON to Kotlin data
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
            .create(SightHoundApiService::class.java) // Create an instance of the API service
    }
}

Here is how i send the request to the api
interface SightHoundApiService {


    @POST(apiURL)
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    fun annotateImageLicensePlate(
        @Header("X-API-KEY") apiKey: String,
        @Body requestBody: LicensePlateRequest
    ): Call<LicensePlateResponse>
}

fun annotateImageLicensePlate(apiKey: String, requestBody: LicensePlateRequest): Call<LicensePlateResponse> {
        Log.d("ApiClient", "Annotating image with API key: $apiKey")
        return RetrofitClient.instance.annotateImageLicensePlate(apiKey, requestBody)

    }

val request = annotateImageLicensePlate(BuildConfig.API_KEY, requestBody)

Here are the log messages
Error: API Error: {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException


Your code is fine, Interceptor will override X-API-KEY from @Header annotation and send it to the server correctly. Please ensure that your API is working correctly with this API key using Postman or a similar tool.

Thanks, turns out the api key was no longer valid, tested it with curl and checked the key after, so thanks :D
